# Rank standings table of soccer matches by H2H

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

Let me start explaining this with an example, I have a table with records of matches played in a soccer league, by using this table and its matches results am able to generate a standings table for the teams in this league via a mysql query.

**Table [matches] (example)**

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
|id  |   hometeam   |goalsfor|goalsagainst|   awayteam   |
 --------------------------------------------------------
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 8 | Real Madrid   |   2    |     0      | Inter Milan  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
| 9 | Inter Milan   |   3    |     3      | Real Madrid  |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

**Generated standings by query**

```
    Pos Team           Pld  W   D   L   F   A   GD  Pts
    1   FC Barcelona    5   2   3   0   8   5   3   9   
    2   Inter Milan     6   2   2   2   11  10  1   8
    3   Real Madrid     6   2   2   2   8   8   0   8
    4   AC Milan        5   0   3   2   8   12  -4  3
```

***The query:***

```
    select 
    team, 
    count(*) played, 
    count(case when goalsfor > goalsagainst then 1 end) wins, 
    count(case when goalsagainst> goalsfor then 1 end) lost, 
    count(case when goalsfor = goalsagainst then 1 end) draws, 
    sum(goalsfor) goalsfor, 
    sum(goalsagainst) goalsagainst, 
    sum(goalsfor) - sum(goalsagainst) goal_diff,
    sum(
          case when goalsfor > goalsagainst then 3 else 0 end 
        + case when goalsfor = goalsagainst then 1 else 0 end
    ) score 
from (
    select hometeam team, goalsfor, goalsagainst from scores 
  union all
    select awayteam, goalsagainst, goalsfor from scores
) a 
group by team
order by score desc, goal_diff desc;
```

What I want to do is to order the standings based on **Head to Head** matches, so it would first order by points, then if there's a draw in points the second sorting would be to look at the two teams matches and compare who has more wins, or scored more than the other, then use that to sort the table.

By doing this as in the example Real Madrid will become ranked as 2nd and then Inter Milan as 3rd.

How can I achieve this?
I want to compare the two teams matches when they are equal in points, and use that to sort.

```
ORDER BY score DESC, h2h DESC; goal_diff DESC
```

> *Update:* I ended going with a solution mix of sql and php, first I find equaled teams in rank, and then generate mini h2h standings for those team and update the rank based on it. I still see this doable with just sql, but with my heavy query its too complicated to implement with just sql, thats why I mixed with php in the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process this in two steps. First, run the query above and store the results in a work table (call it work below). Then you need to get a tie breaker score for each team that is on the same score. Below, I join the matches table to the work table for each team, and ignore any where the work rows do not have the same score, as they are not important. Then give the team 1 if they won. Have to do it again for the other side.  You might want to change this to the 3 for win, 1 for draw.

Sum these results up, join that result to the team row in work, and you have a tie break score for each row where where the score is the same.

You need to check what happens if you have many teams on the same score, and see if this is the result you want.

```
select w.*, b.hth
From work w 
    left outer join (
        select team, SUM(hth) hth 
        from (
            Select hometeam team, case when m.goalsfor > m.goalsagainst then 1 else 0 end hth
            from matches m
                inner join work w1 on m.hometeam = w1.team
                inner join work w2 on m.awayteam = w2.team
            where w1.score = w2.score
            union all
            Select awayteam team, case when m.goalsAgainst > m.goalsFor then 1 else 0 end hth
            from matches m
                inner join work w1 on m.hometeam = w1.team
                inner join work w2 on m.awayteam = w2.team
            where w1.score = w2.score
        ) a  --all hth at same points
        group by team
    ) b  --summed to one row per team
    on b.team = w.team
order by w.score desc, b.hth desc;
```